# JUnit run tests command line

Tags: java, junit

I've got the following structure

```
lib/junit-4.10.jar
tests/Tester.java
tests/Tester.class
build/jar/jar_file.jar
```

(Tester belongs to package tests)

I can compile tests using

```
javac -cp build/jar/jar_file.jar:lib/junit-4.10.jar tests/*.java
```

However I can't seem to run tests:

```
java -cp build/jar/jar_file.jar:lib/junit-4.10.jar org.junit.runner.JUnitCore tests.Tester
```

or

```
java -cp build/jar/jar_file.jar:lib/junit-4.10.jar org.junit.runner.JUnitCore Tester
```

And I get the following output:

```
JUnit version 4.10
Could not find class: tests.Tester

Time: 0.001

OK (0 tests)
```

How do I resolve this `Could not find class` problem? I think it may be classpath related.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Assuming this is Linux/Mac (not Windows) and your path separator is correct (:), since your test class files exist in package subdirectories under the current working directory (.)
You need to add "." to your class path, for example:

```
java -cp .:build/jar/jar_file.jar:lib/junit-4.10.jar org.junit.runner.JUnitCore tests.Tester
```

Comment: I'm having the same problem but adding . didn't help

Answer (score 1):

The classpath should be semi colon separated (on Windows - not sure what you are using.)

```
java -cp build/jar/jar_file.jar;lib/junit-4.10.jar org.junit.runner.JUnitCore tests.Tester
```

Also with this command line you will need to run it in your project root

Comment: semicolons are for Windows only. On Unix, a colon must be used.

Comment: @JBNizet :) good point. I was assuming windows which is not strictly correct. My bad..

Comment: This is what I have been doing, no luck.